# Multiple File Uploads Which Supports all browser specially ie7, ie8 and ie9

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, file-upload

can any one help me through out this problem that i need a code script which supports multiple file uploading in each and every browser.

If i use HTML5 it supports chorme and moxilla firefox but not IE, i am in search of script/jquery which supports all browsers.

I have already used file uploading feature as

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" multiple>
```

but this is not working in IE because it is HTML5 attribute on file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uploadify was good, but it isn't maintaned anymore.
Instead use [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/). It supports "HTML5 Gears, Silverlight, Flash, BrowserPlus or normal forms" that's why it's so awesome (works on any browser) and easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

IE hardly supports html5 and lower versions never will, so its probably best to detect browser and find yourself a different uploader for IE, for example a flash uploader.

Answer (score 3):

Try out this one.
http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Uploadify is a powerful and highly-customizable file upload script.  In its simplest form, Uploadify is easy to get up and running with minimal effort and little coding knowledge.

Uploadify can also be modified to suits the needs of more advanced developers via the arsenal of custom options that are available.  Below are a few examples of different implementations of the Uploadify plugin.
Uploadify is fully customizable and mainly all browser compatible.

Answer (score 2):

best way of multiple image upload is
http://www.uploadify.com/

thanks

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 is still not supported completely by all the browsers and IE is lacking lots of support features where as chrome, firefox are leading one. to checkout how many features your browser supports just go through http://html5test.com/.

now multiple file upload is not supported by IE as mention on http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_multiple.asp. so for now to get this feature i think we will have to go for java script as others have mentioned you can go for http://www.uploadify.com/